# Symfony2/Doctrine use CHAR_LENGTH

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need a simple query to get elements which name is exactly 20 chars

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
                  ->where('CHAR_LENGTH(t.name) = 20');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Char length is unknown for doctrine, but function like DATE_DIFF or CURRENT_DATE work, there is any equivalent to CHAR_LENGTH in Doctrine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LENGTH()` should be the method you are looking for.

> LENGTH(str) - Returns the length of the given string

[Doctrine has a good documentation regarding DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions).

Comment: Thanks for the link I was looking for it

Comment: LENGTH() is byte length which will be correct most times, but not all times for utf8 charsets. CHAR_LENGTH() is character length. I think Doctrine has a bug in this regard in it's getLengthExpression() method.